# The options in the modal made by showInformationMessage are not selectable using keyboard

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

#### Softwared version info

- VS Code Version: 1.86.0-insider Commit: 5d344004f839677def958534b58e854a9ae26fd0
- OS Version: Darwin arm64 23.2.0 - MacOS Sonoma 14.2.1 (23C71)

Does this issue occur when all extensions are disabled?: Yes

#### Steps to Reproduce:

1. Add a command in your vscode extension

```js
    context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('my-extension.getConsent', async () => {
        const res = await vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Get me the consent", { modal: true }, "Yes", "No");
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`Consent: ${res}`);
    }));
```

2. Run this command using vscode's command pallet while your extension is installed and activated in vscode.
3. The modal shows up with options as shown below: 
   [image]

As you can see, there is a selection outline that can be used to move over the options in the modal. The issue here is that the outline does not represent the option to be selected.
4. When I toggle the outline to the option "No" or "Cancel" and press enter, The selected answer still comes up as "Yes" as shown in the video below:

#### Issue Demo

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/assets/44257152/dbc0572d-a8b7-4ee6-9b06-aa760b0a37ce

[image]

#### My Question:

Is there a way to select an option using keyboard in the modal created using vscode.window.showInformationMessage ?

#### What I tried

I tried to select the options as shown in the attached video. My intention was to select the option of my choice using tab button and press enter to confirm my choice. But only the highlighted "Yes" option was being chosen unless I specifically click on the option using a mouse cursor.

#### What I expect

I am expecting that the user should be able to toggle the selected option using the keyboard's tab button and press enter to select the option of his choice.

Comment: Make a gif showing the issue and add it to your question - I don't want to download a file...

Comment: Added demo gif as per your request @Mark 
Please let me know any solutions for the question.